# Are there any good Apple Watch apps to track roller skating?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-watch

I've looked around for a bit but i wasn't able to find any app to track roller skating. The only app that i found is iSkate but it's pretty outdated and it costs about 10€ that it's too expensive to me.

Answer (score 0):

there is! I use an app called 'sports tracker'. There are a lot of different kind of exercises to track, including roller skating ;